# How to perform lock on desktop folder using java

Tags: java, swing

I have one folder on desktop with name of ABC. Now, I want to write an java program for this folder for security. I mean if any user click on ABC folder the before opening the ABC folder
it should ask for login first. If user is not valid then he cant open the ABC folder.

So I want to  perform this thing through java swing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this can be done using java. If it was possible, it would be an unholy mess anyway because you'd have to change the default handler for **all folders** to your java program, not just the folder that you want to protect. Also, it would be insecure because there would be nothing stopping people from using another file manager to open the folder, bypassing your security entirely.

You could, however, implement your own pseudo folder security by using java to encrypt files, but that would obviously not be a standard folder on your desktop.

Why do you insist on using java? Have you heard of truecrypt?

Comment: Tnx for reply. i do not know about truecrypt.